# Swagger Python Get A Upload File Path

Tags: python, file-upload, swagger

[image]

I am doing autosave_image_path API, but I got a problem, I don't know how to make that show a `select_file`.(like below)

[image]

My api.py model.py module.py, three python file will work together.

```py
# api.py
@api.route("/autosave_image_path")
class AutosaveImagePath(CustomResource):
    @api.expect(autosave_image_path_input_payload)
    @api.marshal_with(autosave_image_path_output_payload)
    def post(self):
        data = api.payload
        # response = request.files.get('file')
        # file=request.files.getlist('file')[0]

        return Account.autosave_image_path(data=data)
# model.py
autosave_image_path_input_payload = api.model(f'autosave_image_path帳號input',{
    "uuid":fields.String(require=True,example=generate_short_unique_id()),
    "front_path":fields.String(require=True,example='front_path'),
    "back_path":fields.String(require=True,example='back_path')
    
    }
)   

autosave_image_path_output_payload =api.clone(u'autosave_image_path帳號output', base_input_payload)


    # module.py
    @staticmethod
    def autosave_image_path(data):
        try:
            print(data)

            OracleAccess.execute(f'INSERT INTO {TBL_USER_IMAGE_PATH} (UUID, FRONT_PATH, BACK_PATH) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)',
                                (data['uuid'], data['front_path'], data['back_path']))
            

            return {
                "result": 0,
                "message": "Suc.",
            }
        except Exception as e:
            return {
                "result": -1,
                "message": f"Error: {str(e)}",
            }
```

I show my another API like this for you can understand what I am taking.
Below is a successful API about `add_account_list`:

```
@staticmethod
    def add_account_list(user_id, role, email):
        try:
            if Account.account_exist(user_id):
                return {"message": "alerdy_exist", "RESULT": "1"}
            
            OracleAccess.execute(
                f"INSERT INTO {TBL_USER_ACCOUNT} (USER_ID, ROLE, EMAIL) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)",
                (user_id, ','.join(role), email)  
            )
            return {"message": "Succfully", "RESULT": "0"}
        
        except Exception as e:
            return {"message": f"ERROR: {str(e)}", "RESULT": "-1"}

@api.route("/add_account_list")
class AddAccountList(CustomResource):
    @api.expect(add_account_list_input_payload)
    def post(self):
        data = api.payload
        return Account.add_account_list(
            user_id=data["user_id"], role=data["role"], email=data["email"]
        )
add_account_list_input_payload = api.model(
    "add_account_list帳號input",
    {
        "user_id": fields.String(required=True, example=""),
        "role": fields.List(fields.String, required=True, example=[]),
        "email": fields.String(required=True, example=""),
    },
)
add_account_list_output_payload = api.clone("add_account_list帳號output", base_input_payload)
```

I would be like add this select_file box:

[image]

from

[image]

upload a file, load file path, and then INSERT INTO my database.